# PHP, How do exceptions really work?

Tags: php, exception, transactions

I know what exceptions are and I know when to use them but today, I read from this blog [Destructing PHP](http://schlueters.de/blog/). It has the below code

```
require('autoload.php');

function foo($db, $data) {
    $db->beginTransaction();

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $db->insert($row);
    }

    $db->commit();
}

$db = db::factory();
$data = data::factory();

try {
    foo($db, $data);
} catch (Exception $e) {}

$db->insert(data::finalData());
```

> According to the program the data::finalData() should be stored independently from whether foo() succeeds or not. Unfortunately this isn't the case: If something in the loop inside foo() throws there will be an open transaction. The final data now becomes part of that transaction. As there is no further handling PHP will clean-up at the end of this program and automatically rewind the transaction.

The confusing part is `The final data now becomes part of that transaction`.
This conflicts with my understanding of exceptions, I have known exceptions to start execution from where `throw` was called when there are caught, in this case somewhere in the foreach and continue to the end of foo function executing `$db->commit()` along effectively closing the DB transaction.
With this observation, final data should never become part of transaction like the author says.

Comment: If an exception gets thrown the transaction is _not_ committed, obviously. That means the last line in that code snippet will insert the "final data" as part of the (not yet) committed transaction. That is because the exception is caught and normal processing resumed. That's all.

Comment: @arkascha I want to know why `$db->commit()` is not executed when exception is throw one line above it. or generally where execution start after a caught exeception

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry, I did not realize you ask about how exceptions work... The commit directive is last in the function. If an exception is raised (that can only happen inside the function since the try-catch block only contains the call to that function), then that functions code is _not_ processed to the end, obviously. So no commit is done. Instead execution proceeds in the catch block (which is empty, so the exception is "swallowed") and then goes on just after the catch block and executes the "final data" directive. Execution does _not_ somehow jump back after an exception has been caught!

Comment: That is very helpful. if you can make it an answer

Comment: Sure, posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commit directive is last in function `foo()`. If an exception is raised (that can only happen inside the function since the try-catch block only contains the call to that function), then that functions code is *not* processed to the end, obviously. So no commit is performed, the transaction "hangs".

Execution proceeds in the catch block (which is empty, so the exception is "swallowed") and then goes on normally just after the catch block and executes the "final data" directive. So the commit directive in the function is *never* executed, the transaction still accepts statements. That is why the "final data" gets part of that transaction.

Execution does not somehow jump back after an exception has been caught! That is the whole point of an exception: to immediately leave the failing code and return to the calling / controlling scope.